# Generate and place random points inside a circle

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, shapes, zelle-graphics

I have a task where I am supposed to create a circle and plot some random points inside it. 
I am new to Python and Python libraries. 
I need some suggestions about different software or packages that might help me with my task.

I have seen some YouTube videos, but they were not relevant to my topic. 
This is the code I saw in a tutorial to create a circle:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
        win = GraphWin("my window",500,500)
        pt = Point(250,250)
        win.setBackground(color_rgb(255,255,255))
        cir = Circle(pt,50)
        cir.draw(win)
        win.getMouse()
        win.close()
main()
```

Can I continue with this graphics class to complete my task? 
If not, then please suggest a good library or s/w.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tkinter`, and a `canvas` widget.

The following example traces a circle centered at 200, 200 on the canvas. Upon a mouse click, the distance from the center is calculated, and if it is smaller than the radius, a point is drawn on the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk


def distance_to_center(x, y):
    return ((x-200)**2 + (y-200)**2)**0.5

def place_point(e):
    if distance_to_center(e.x, e.y) < 100:
        canvas.create_oval(e.x-2, e.y-2, e.x+2, e.y+2)


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 300, 300)
canvas.pack()

canvas.bind('<1>', place_point)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my reimplementation of @ReblochonMasque's tkinter example (+1) using turtle graphics:

```
import turtle

LARGE_RADIUS, SMALL_DIAMETER = 100, 4

def place_point(x, y):
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    if turtle.distance(0, 0) < LARGE_RADIUS:
        turtle.dot(SMALL_DIAMETER)

turtle.setup(width=400, height=400)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-LARGE_RADIUS)  # center circle at (0, 0)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(LARGE_RADIUS)
turtle.penup()

turtle.onscreenclick(place_point)
turtle.mainloop()
```

Although, like Zelle graphics.py, turtle graphics is implemented atop tkinter, it uses a different coordinate system.  In terms of complexity and capability:

```
Zelle graphics.py < turtle < tkinter
```

If you find tkinter too complex for your needs, and Zelle graphics.py insufficient, consider turtle graphics, which, like tkinter, comes with Python.

> Can I continue with this graphics class to complete my task?

Possibly.  Here's an example next step from where you left off:

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
LARGE_RADIUS, SMALL_RADIUS = 50, 2
CENTER = Point(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)

def distance_to_center(point):
    return ((point.getX() - CENTER.getX())**2 + (point.getY()- CENTER.getY())**2) ** 0.5

win = GraphWin("My Window", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
circle = Circle(CENTER, LARGE_RADIUS)
circle.draw(win)

while True:
    point = win.getMouse()

    if distance_to_center(point) < LARGE_RADIUS:
        dot = Circle(point, SMALL_RADIUS)
        dot.draw(win)
```